# Mocking function call when called from certain method

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I am facing a scenario where I have to mock a certain method only when it is being invoked from very specific method. For example here is the sample code:

```
public class TestMethod {
    public boolean testMethod() {
        return false;
    }
}

public class ClassToBeTested {
    private TestMethod testMethod;

    public ClassToBeTested() {
        testMethod = new TestMethod();
    }
    public boolean evaluateSomething() {
        boolean evaluation1Ans = evaluate1();
        boolean evaluation2Ans = evaluate2();
        return !evaluation1Ans && evaluation2Ans;
    }

    public boolean evaluate1() {
        boolean expr = testMethod.testMethod();
        return expr;
    }

    public boolean evaluate2() {
        return testMethod.testMethod() && evaluateBooleanExpression();
    }

    private boolean evaluateBooleanExpression() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class MockitoExperiement {
    @Test
    public void testEvaluateSomething() throws Exception {
        ClassToBeTested classToBeTested = new ClassToBeTested();
        TestMethod testMethod = mock(TestMethod.class);
        when(testMethod.testMethod()).thenAnswer((Answer<Boolean>) invocationOnMock -> {
            if(new Object() {}
                    .getClass()
                    .getEnclosingMethod()
                    .getName().equals("evaluate2")) return true;
            else
                return false;
        });

        boolean flag = classToBeTested.evaluateSomething();
        System.out.print("");
    }
}
```

Here despite doing conditional mocking I am still receiving false from the method to be invoked. Where I am making a mistake in this sample?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getEnclosingMethod() returning Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70767101/getenclosingmethod-returning-null)

Comment: Or maybe this is a better answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/442773/29470

Comment: In short, `Class.getEnclosingMethod` has nothing to do with the call stack. It tells you where the anonymous class is _defined_ (in this case, the lambda passed to `thenAnswer`).

Comment: One of the problems and a partial solution: [Why is my class not calling my mocked methods in unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74027324/112968) (but not an exact dupe)

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually using the mock that you have created. You are still calling the `testMethod` method on the original `testMethod` object that is created in the `ClassToBeTested` constructor.

To use the mock that you have created, you need to inject it into the `ClassToBeTested` object and use it instead of the original `testMethod` object. You can do this by adding a setter method for the `testMethod` field in the `ClassToBeTested` class, and then using this setter to set the mock as the `testMethod` object before calling the `evaluateSomething` method.

Updated code below:

```
public class ClassToBeTested {
    private TestMethod testMethod;

    public ClassToBeTested() {
        testMethod = new TestMethod();
    }

    public void setTestMethod(TestMethod testMethod) {
        this.testMethod = testMethod;
    }

    public boolean evaluateSomething() {
        boolean evaluation1Ans = evaluate1();
        boolean evaluation2Ans = evaluate2();
        return !evaluation1Ans && evaluation2Ans;
    }

    public boolean evaluate1() {
        boolean expr = testMethod.testMethod();
        return expr;
    }

    public boolean evaluate2() {
        return testMethod.testMethod() && evaluateBooleanExpression();
    }

    private boolean evaluateBooleanExpression() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class MockitoExperiment {
    @Test
    public void testEvaluateSomething() throws Exception {
        ClassToBeTested classToBeTested = new ClassToBeTested();
        TestMethod testMethod = mock(TestMethod.class);
        when(testMethod.testMethod()).thenAnswer((Answer<Boolean>) invocationOnMock -> {
            if (new Object() {
            }
                    .getClass()
                    .getEnclosingMethod()
                    .getName().equals("evaluate2")) return true;
            else
                return false;
        });

        classToBeTested.setTestMethod(testMethod);//setting the object here
        boolean flag = classToBeTested.evaluateSomething();
        System.out.print("");
    }
}
```